# BeautifulSoup - Avoid considering elements containing <br> as different elements using findAll

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following html snippet:

```
<div id="targetdown" class="content">
    <div class="alertbox">
        <div class="ym-wrapper">
            <div class="ym-wbox">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
        <div class="ym-wbox">
            <p style="text-align: center;">EXCEL Physical Therapy has been keeping our patients moving forward<br />
for nearly 30 years. In the process, we have built an unparalleled<br />
reputation&nbsp;by combining the highest quality of physical therapy<br />
with exceptional&nbsp;customer service to provide a genuinely<br />
&ldquo;patient first&rdquo; approach.&nbsp;It is this philosophy&nbsp;that has established<br />
EXCEL&nbsp;as&nbsp;a premier physical therapy provider in Northern New Jersey.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<section class="parallaxone parallax">
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
        <div class="ym-wbox">
            <h2>Helping you navigate the road to recovery</h2>


        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want to get the text from the elements present, but not to consider that when there's a line break it's a new element.

I'm doing the following:

```
'
In [19]: html = '<div id="targetdown" class="content"><div class="alertbox"><div class="ym-wrapper"><div class="ym-wbox"></div></div></div><div class="ym-wrapper"><div class="ym-wbox"><p style="text-align: center;">EXCEL Physical Therapy has been keeping our patients moving forward<br />for nearly 30 years. In the process, we have built an unparalleled<br /> reputation&nbsp;by combining the highest quality of physical therapy<br /> with exceptional&nbsp;customer service to provide a genuinely<br /> &ldquo;patient first&rdquo; approach.&nbsp;It is this philosophy&nbsp;that has established<br /> EXCEL&nbsp;as&nbsp;a premier physical therapy provider in Northern New Jersey.</p></div></div></div><section class="parallaxone parallax"><div class="ym-wrapper"><div class="ym-wbox"><h2>Helping you navigate the road to recovery</h2> </div></div></section>
    ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    ...: texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
```

And the result is:

```
In [20]: texts
Out[20]:
['EXCEL Physical Therapy has been keeping our patients moving forward',
 'for nearly 30 years. In the process, we have built an unparalleled',
 ' reputation\xa0by combining the highest quality of physical therapy',
 ' with exceptional\xa0customer service to provide a genuinely',
 ' “patient first” approach.\xa0It is this philosophy\xa0that has established',
 ' EXCEL\xa0as\xa0a premier physical therapy provider in Northern New Jersey.',
 'Helping you navigate the road to recovery',
 ' ']
```

How do avoid this splitting in the linebreak tags so that the text

> EXCEL Physical Therapy has been keeping our patients moving forward for nearly 30 years. In the process, we have built an
>   unparalleled
>  reputation by combining the highest quality of
>   physical therapy
>  with exceptional customer service to
>   provide a genuinely
>  “patient first”
>   approach. It is this philosophy that has established
>   EXCEL as a premier physical therapy provider in Northern New
>   Jersey.

is returned as one single element in the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
soup.find_all("div", class_="ym-wbox")[1].find("p").text
```

Comment: I want it to be general, not just for this case. For my specific purpose, I am trying to extract all the visible text in a page by using soup.findAll(text=True) and then filtering it for elements like script, head, and so on. Which works fine, except for the fact that bs breaks the elements in the <b>

Comment: All the text in the page is simply `soup.text`

Comment: I also need the text from different elements to be go into different list elements, because I want to do text processing in each one of them individually.

Comment: What do you mean different elements? Your expected output is achieved using either one of the options I posted...if not, edit your question to explain what the expected output is.